# Soft Keyboard always appears on WebView

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

I have a `WebView` with an input tag inside. I ve created my custom keyboard (by extending `KeyboardView`) to type only some characters in.

But when I "click" on this input tag, the softKeyboard of Android appears, despite having set `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden`", and `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing`".

Anybody can help me to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please try following two options `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize"`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work.